# Possible to synchronise "Allow Relay" among multiple hub servers?

Tags: exchange-2010

We have several hub servers that are exposed to the internet.

My problem is that each server needs to have a local receive connector set up, and updated as new IP addresses are added as an allowed relay for that connector.

Is there any way to synchronize the configuration for the hub servers?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's nothing out of the box that will do that. I use a [Powershell loop](https://serverfault.com/questions/634466/looping-get-receiveconnector-to-grab-multiple-receive-connectors/634486#634486) every time I add an IP so that it hits all the appropriate connectors - either save them in an array, or use a naming convention that will only match the ones you want to be relaying.

So you might want something like this, with your new sending IPs in a CSV file.

```
$rcs = Get-ReceiveConnector | ? {$_.name -like "*relay*"  }
foreach ($rc in $rcs) {
$impcsv = import-csv ipranges.csv
foreach($line in $impcsv)
    {
        $ipAdd = $line.LowerBound
        $newconn = Get-ReceiveConnector $rc
        $newconn.RemoteIPRanges += $ipAdd
        Set-ReceiveConnector $rc -RemoteIPRanges $newConn.RemoteIPRanges 
    }   
}
```